# Can an Intellij Scratch file be used to query via a JpaRepository interface?

Tags: spring, jpa, kotlin, intellij-idea

Intellij has a useful feature called a "Scratch File" that allows you to try adhoc Java/Kotlin code against your module(s). I'd like to use this in a Spring/Hibernate project.

Is it possible to induce Spring to create all of the proxies and autowired bits necessary such that a JpaRepository interface can be used for adhoc method calls (and thus, try out specific database queries)?

For example:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
import java.util.*

interface UserRecordRepository : JpaRepository<UserRecord, UUID> {
  fun findByIdAndDeletedIsFalse(id: UUID): UserRecord
  ...
}
```

How might I call `findByIdAndDeletedIsFalse` from a Scratch file?